# Setting CORS in Azure Functions running inside docker container

Tags: docker, cors, azure-functions

I have created an azure function that exposes an API that is being used in another project. I would like to enable the team that works on the front end to have a Docker image of our API to help them in their development. I have packed my azure function using the Dockerfile that is being generated when running `func init LocalFunctionsProject --worker-runtime dotnet --docker` as per [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=bash%2Cportal&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

This results in the following Dockerfile contents:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS installer-env

COPY . /src/dotnet-function-app
RUN cd /src/dotnet-function-app && \
    mkdir -p /home/site/wwwroot && \
    dotnet publish *.csproj --output /home/site/wwwroot

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:2.0
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true


COPY --from=installer-env ["/home/site/wwwroot", "/home/site/wwwroot"]
```

I have then created a `docker-compose.yml` file on the front end project:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  frontend:
    image: frontend:latest
    build: .  
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"  
    env_file: 
      - frontend.docker.env
  backend: 
    image: backend:latest
    env_file:
      - backend.docker.env
    ports: 
      - "8080:80"
```

This succesfully spins up two containers, one with the front end and another with the backend. Inside my `frontend.docker.env` I have set my variable to point to the `backend` so that calls from the front end are directed to `http://backend/api/myendpoint`
**However** this is where everything fails, Im getting a CORS issue:

**What I have tried**:

1. Whenever I call my backend from the exposed 8080 port from Postman, everyhting is working fine. I have tried to manually add an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set to `*` on my response which I can verify is coming through in Postman. However the front end is still getting the CORS issue.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at *http://backend/api/myendpoint*. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

2. My other approach is changing the `web.config` inside the `azure-functions-host` file manually by running the following instruction on my Dockerfile:

`RUN sed -i 's/<customHeaders>/<customHeaders><add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" \/><add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" \/><add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" \/>/g' azure-functions-host/web.config`

After that I see the following headers coming from the response in Postman:

> Access-Control-Allow-Headers = X-Requested-With,content-type
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods = GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin = *

However Im still facing the same issue. Postman works, the frontend doesnt...
Do you have any idea what the issue might be, or how to properly set CORS

Comment: Something similar is being discussed here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5090.

Comment: Sadly none of the answers work for me :(

Comment: @LuisBecerril have you fixed it?

Comment: Sadly, I havent been able to fix it @XardasLord

Comment: I fixed IT by just enable nginx container and proxy the network calls through that reverse proxy

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and fixed it by adding this to DockerFile

```
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true \ 
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS="[\"*\"]" \
CONTAINER_NAME="yaradbg.dev" \
ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:7071
```

Pay attention to " as this is to make the string a valid JSON string. You can restrict access by changing * to a specific domain if needed.

You can see the complete docker file here:
[yaradbg-container Dockerfile](https://github.com/DissectMalware/yaradbg-container)

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm comming little bit late, but I came across the same issue and I think I found a solution to it. I found it here - https://hexmaster.nl/posts/container-apps-cors-settings/

[image]

This is my docker-compose.yml file, In the article I've linked, Eduard mentions that you need include env variable CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS which is applied only when other env variable is included - CONTAINER_NAME, which can be any string

[image]

this is how my .env file for docker looks like